# How to convert a Json Array to a JSON Object and keep the order of elements

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object, wanted to sort it, so I converted it to a JSON array
now after sorting json array i want to convert it to json object as it was at the beginning without losing the order of the elements

the JSON Array :

```
grille.weeks = [{
  "2020_1": {
    "calculated": "18.00",
    "ddeb": "2020-01-01",
    "dfin": "2020-01-05",
    "partiel": true,
    "planified": "",
    "productiveRealised": "",
    "realised": ""
  }
}, {
  "2020_2": {
    "calculated": "35.00",
    "ddeb": "2020-01-06",
    "dfin": "2020-01-12",
    "partiel": false,
    "planified": "",
    "productiveRealised": "",
    "realised": ""
  }
}]}
```

I want to convert it to this JSON Object :

```
grille.weeks = {
  "2020_1": {
    "calculated": "18.00",
    "ddeb": "2020-01-01",
    "dfin": "2020-01-05",
    "partiel": true,
    "planified": "",
    "productiveRealised": "",
    "realised": ""
  }
, 
  "2020_2": {
    "calculated": "35.00",
    "ddeb": "2020-01-06",
    "dfin": "2020-01-12",
    "partiel": false,
    "planified": "",
    "productiveRealised": "",
    "realised": ""
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: An object is unordered, and given its an object the order shouldnt matter? If you want to keep the order use the array.

Comment: In addition to what *Craicerjack* already did point to, one should be aware that for each JS environment one has to check if an `Object`-object's (creation) key order can be guarantied... [***Objects vs Maps***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_vs._Maps)... [Out Of Order Keys in ES6 Objects](https://hackernoon.com/out-of-order-keys-in-es6-objects-d5cede7dc92e)... Thus every answer that makes use of SO's own implementation of `console.log` for `Object` references does not prove anything.  If at all then `console.log(Object.keys(obj))`.

Comment: @Craicerjack well i can't I'm forced to store the JSON object in the DB  in  this format ... the solution below works perfectly and keeps the order

Comment: @PeterSeliger sorry in fact they are quoted .. I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help, I found a solution for my situation and wanted to share it with you ... although I don't recommend it just for such cases

the solution is:

I created a function which gets the keys from the jsonObject and sorts them, then with a loop I concat my objects into a string variable using the sorted keys

```
  function toString(obj){         
                             
    var str="{\"weeks\":{";
    Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b){
//I split the key to sort it properly ex : "2020_1" => [2020,1]
          var yeara = parseInt(a.split('_')[0]);
          var yearb  = parseInt(b.split('_')[0]);
          var indicea = parseInt(a.split('_')[1]);
          var indiceb = parseInt(b.split('_')[1]);
          
          if(yeara==yearb){
          if(indicea>indiceb) return 1
          if(indicea<indiceb ) return -1
          if(indicea==indiceb ) return 0
          
          }
          if(yeara>yearb) return 1
          if(yeara<yearb) return -1
          
          }).forEach(function(key,idx,array) {
          if(idx == array.length-1)
          str+='"'+key+'":'+JSON.stringify(obj[key]) 
          else
          str+='"'+key+'":'+JSON.stringify(obj[key])+','
      
    })
    
    str+="}}";
     return str;
    }
```

NB : the answers above works perfectly for regular environment

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const before = [{
  2020_1: {
    calculated: "18.00",
    ddeb: "2020-01-01",
    dfin: "2020-01-05",
    partiel: true,
    planified: "",
    productiveRealised: "",
    realised: ""
  }
}, {
  2020_2: {
    calculated: "35.00",
    ddeb: "2020-01-06",
    dfin: "2020-01-12",
    partiel: false,
    planified: "",
    productiveRealised: "",
    realised: ""
  }
}];

const after = before.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }));

console.log(after);
```

#### Edit: Without ES6 Syntax

```js
var before = [{
  2020_1: {
    calculated: "18.00",
    ddeb: "2020-01-01",
    dfin: "2020-01-05",
    partiel: true,
    planified: "",
    productiveRealised: "",
    realised: ""
  }
}, {
  2020_2: {
    calculated: "35.00",
    ddeb: "2020-01-06",
    dfin: "2020-01-12",
    partiel: false,
    planified: "",
    productiveRealised: "",
    realised: ""
  }
}];

var after = {};

for(var i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
  Object.assign(after, before[i]);
}

console.log(after);
```

Comment: this code work perfectly but not for me, cause I'm working in an old version of javascript so the lambda expression doesn't work for me ... is there any older way to do it ?

Comment: @AmineChoukri Checkout the updated solution, it should work fine in legacy environments.

Comment: @HaoWu ... regarding the second approach, if one makes use of `Object.assign` one very safely can keep the `reduce`; just with a good old function expression instead of the fat arrow thing.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I wasn't sure so I didn't use any *fancy* array functions  Also it's a good opportunity to show there are different approaches to do it.

Comment: @HaoWu unfortunately the same prblm ... "Object.assign" doesn't work for me ...

Comment: @AmineChoukri ... can you please tell us then in detail about your special environment by editing your original Q. accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterSeliger well it's an old java desktop application which contains a javascript compiler, and from what i can see it accept only the pure javascript (old versions)

Comment: @AmineChoukri ... in this case you either try to polyfill `Object.assign` and hope for the best in terms of your environment keeps/supports an object's key creation order, or, what I would advice, think about your needs/requirements of creating an object with strictly ordered keys instead of continuing with an ordered list of objects.

Comment: @PeterSeliger well the main problem here is to order the json Object .. and to do that I converted it to a Json array ... I will try to polyfill it like you said thanks